# Fermat's little theorem and Euler's criterion

Tags: congruences, quadratic-reciprocity, euler-lagrange-equation

Is it possible to find the solution of this congruence by Fermat's little theorem and how ?

$$15125^{2401}\pmod {72}$$

Can somebody tell me how to do it by Euler's criterion?

Comment: For Euler's Theorem, note that $\varphi(72)=24$, so $15125^{2400}\equiv 1\pmod{72}$.